# How to work concurrently two different threads which have the same priority?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working with one Queue i.e. [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). I am trying to make one app which has two threads with equal priority. First Thread will continuously add element into the Queue and second Thread will continuously poll from the same Queue.

**Program:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Demo {

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> list = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10000);
    public int count;

    public  void insert() {
        while (true) {
            list.add(count);
            System.out.println(" inserted : "+count);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public  void remove()  {
        while (true) {
            try {
                int pollElement = (int) list.take();
                System.out.println("removed : " + pollElement);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo main = new Demo();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                main.insert();
            }
        };
        thread1.start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                main.remove();
            }
        };
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Above Program will frequently generate output like below:

```
removed : 4992
removed : 4993
inserted : 5195
removed : 4994
inserted : 5196
removed : 4995
inserted : 5197
removed : 4996
inserted : 5198
inserted : 5199
inserted : 5200
inserted : 5201
inserted : 5202
```

**Actual Requirement:**

I want the behavior of this app like if one element get inserted into the queue then Second thread get notified for particular insert operation so that it can poll from same queue. i.e. I don't want continuous insert operation or continuous poll operation.

Let's consider, count variable is nothing but continuously pulling the data from the server which is continuously getting inserted into the queue. If continuous poll operation are happening on the queue then I'm missing server data which is coming at that particular time while poll operations are working.

Comment: I don't quite follow your last paragraph. The whole point of a *queue* is to accumulate in-flight requests. If a second (a third etc) request comes in while the first is being processed, it gets added to the queue. It then gets processed when the processor thread is done with the first request. Nothing gets lost.

Comment: Create a `BlockingQueue` of size 1 instead of 10000?

Comment: @JanezKuhar- I don't want to put any kind of delay in adding element into the queue because I'm losing server data which is coming very fast. If I kept the size of queue to 1 instead of 10000 then add need to wait until it becomes poll from the queue.

Comment: This is not how the Scheduler works. Once the thread gets scheduled, it should do as much as it can before the OS schedules another thread, so be happy it pushed multiple items in its small timeframe.

Comment: @Ani perhaps you were looking for something with wait/notify then, as Jigar Joshi suggested (sadly he deleted his asnwer now for some reason). You certainly haven't made yourself very clear.

Comment: I would question the whole design. I would use one thread, reading from the server and processing. You don't want two threads and a queue: if reading is slower than processing there will never be more than one thing in the queue, and if reading is faster than processing you risk running out of memory, or else you will have to use a bounded queue. In none of these cases is there any benefit from multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use an `AtomicBoolean` to simulate it.

```
private AtomicBoolean aBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(true); // init value - true
```

Then you add a condition in your `insert` and `remove` methods

```
public  void insert() {
    while (true) {
        if(aBoolean.get()) {
            list.add(count);
            System.out.println(" inserted : "+ count);
            count++;
            aBoolean.getAndSet(false);
        }
    }
}



public  void remove()  {
    while (true) {
        if(!aBoolean.get()) {
            try {
                int pollElement = (int) list.take();
                System.out.println("removed : " + pollElement);
                aBoolean.getAndSet(true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So you only are allowed to insert elements if `aBoolean` is true and remove elements it `aBoolean` is false. `AtomicBoolean` is `thread-safe. After insert/delete you change the`aBoolean`` to the opposite value so that the other thread can perform it's task.

This is the output :

```
inserted : 0
removed : 0
inserted : 1
removed : 1
inserted : 2
removed : 2
inserted : 3
removed : 3
inserted : 4
removed : 4
inserted : 5
removed : 5
inserted : 6
removed : 6
inserted : 7
removed : 7
```

Comment: @SchiduLuca- Thanks for your answer. In your answer, Insert Thread is waiting until Process/poll thread will not get polled and processed element. I don't want to wait to Insert Thread. It should be continuously inserting i.e. independently.